# Посоветуете, с чего начать, чтобы начать менять верстку странички?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, дизайн, ux

Для своего резюме сделал [страничку](http://splincode.github.io/), но мой преподаватель в университете сказал, что это не очень красиво и свежо. Я вроде бы стараюсь следить за актуальными вещами в веб-программировании, но на скорую руку сами понимаете.

1. Что лучше изменить в верстке?
2. Что лучше в использовать в дизайне, ux?
3. Отчего зависит fps слайдеров, на страничке тормозит слайдер и видео на заднем фоне, как можно это оптимизировать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почитайте что-нибудь о дизайне и почему делаются то или иное действие. Не поленитесь посмотреть работы крупных сайтов и проследить за последними трендами в этом деле.

О дизайне:

1. Задний динамический фон это конечно круто, но зачем? Вы отвлекаете пользователя от просмотра интересующей его информации и ставите в тупик. Это не самое лучшее решение, даже если Вам надо чем-то забить пространство. Спокойный, не чисто белый фон намного лучше. Очень многих приходиться отговаривать от этой заманчивой идее, так как пользователям это не нравится.
2. В графе знания и опыт курсор приобретает форму руки - это явный признак элемента, по которому можно кликать. При клике, конечно ничего не происходит, а значит Вы сбиваете пользователя с толку.
3. При наведении Вы показываете какие-то оценки, то есть я так понимаю Ваш уровень. Это скрытая информацию, которая важна пользователю. Представьте, что он не стал по ним водить, а просто прочитал. У него сложится впечатление, что весь список Вы знаете на твердую пятерку.
4. Посмотрите, как оформляются страницы портфолио у крупных сайтов. Не бойтесь отвести под них отдельное место ниже самого резюме с крупными и красивыми фотографиями, описаниями и ссылками. Первое, что должен увидеть потенциальный работодатель, это успехи соискателя и желательно в красивой графической форме.

О коде:

Каждый байт, переданный по сети занимает время. Чем больше Ваши картинки, тем больше времени требуется на их загрузку и отображение. Что бы уменьшить это время использую специальные preview уменьшенные версии, а по клику уже открывают большие оригиналы. Так же есть возможность подгрузить изображения заранее, в книгах по оптимизации HTML+JS это описано.

Что почитать: единственное, что я помню, это книгу Стива Круга "Не заставляйте меня думать". Остальные книги я уже не помню и большинство брал из разрозненных статей из интернета.